# how to put some default value like "9999-12-31" in date field where we have null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]

**test** is a dataframe with **t_dob** a date field which has null value in it. I want to hardcode a value like "9999-12-31" whenever i have null in date filed using spark scala. Could not find any such option in na.fill() method for date field. Could anyone let me know how this can be done.

Expected output is as below :-

+-------------+-------+-----+
|s_customer_id| s_name|t_dob|
+-------------+-------+-----+
|          101|shameer| 9999-12-31|
|          102| rajesh| 9999-12-31|
+-------------+-------+-----+

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

```
val spark = getSession()

    val data = Seq(("101", "Shameer", null),
      ("102", "Rajesh", new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime)))


    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("s_customer_id", "s_name", "t_dob")

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, when, to_date}
    df.withColumn("t_dob", when($"t_dob".isNull, to_date(lit("9999-12-31"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).otherwise($"t_dob")).show()
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+-------+----------+
|s_customer_id| s_name|     t_dob|
+-------------+-------+----------+
|          101|Shameer|9999-12-31|
|          102| Rajesh|2019-02-21|
+-------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: The coalesce SQL function is shorthand for if null then this. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce-scala.collection.Seq-

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:      var newTest = test.withColumn("t_dob_chnaged", when(col("t_dob").isin(null), "9999-12-31"))

Comment: Thanks Sanjeet.
But the above new column t_dob_chnaged is having  a data type of String and not Date. I want the datatype to be date.

I am not able to use below code as well :-

test.withColumn("t_dob_change", when(col("t_dob").isNull,to_date("9999-12-31")))

as its expecting a column name instead of string "9999-12-31"